# Nhibernate criteria expression.in with string of csv

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

Hello Is it possible in nhibernate to createCriteria expression.in with string of csv, for example

```
public static List<T> ToList(string csvOnly)
    {
        ISession session = NhSessionMenager.Instance.GetSession();
        List<T> l = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).Add(Expression.In("Id",csvOnly)).List<T>().ToList();
        return l;
    }
```

and the string will be: "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use `string.split` to split these up into an array.  I don't think Expression.In takes a comma separated string.

```
string [] split = csvOnly.Split(new Char [] {','});
List<T> l = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).Add(Expression.In("Id",split)).List<T>().ToList();
```

Comment: This option has low performance on memory saving if you give it 1000rows in string;)

Comment: I would be more worried about the sql query at that point then I would be about performance of doing a `string.split`

Comment: On some database engines you have a limit of query parameters. In SQL Server it is something around 2000. We already had that problem.